# kotlin maven compiler unresolved reference to local dependency

Tags: spring-boot, maven, kotlin

Googled all the Internet, I don’t know how to fix it.
The bottom line: there are 3 spring boot applications (microservices) written in Kotlin with this folder structure

```
parent-folder:
  -api
  -service1
  -service2
```

`parent-folder` is just a folder for convenience in which microservices are added.
api is a spring boot application, but in it only utility classes are common for all other microservices
in the folder with `api` I do `mvn install`, the jar is installed and gets into the `.m2/` folder
this is the installed service I add to the `service1` dependency and when I try to do
  `mvn install`, in the folder with `service1` I get the error `Error: (4,21) kotlin: Unresolved reference: api`
for clarity, here is a screen of the pom `Api` service[image]

dependency in `service1`
[image]

compile plugin of `service1`
[image]

when I try to make `mvn install` in `service1` I get an error which indicates to [image]

maven kotlin compiler just does not see the package, but everything is working in the intellij idea if i run it as application, I don’t know what i should to do; why the kotlin maven compiler does not want to get the dependency from the local maven
inside jar api there are such classes
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case the solution was in logic of jar generation
`api` service was a spring project, when i try to do `mvn clean install` it creates `jar` with structure:

```
api.jar
    -META-INF
    -BOOT-INF
```

but when another service use it maven cant find required packages because it was looking in in package name but not in META or BOOT folders

IMPORTANT NOTE!
when you create folders inside project like src/main/kotlin maven-kotlin-compiler will create generated classes in jar inside META folder, but if you create src/main/java it will create jar that will contain generated classes inside folder that have same name that your package name